# Как максимально сжать качество видео, проигрываемое в браузере?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

есть проект на **selenium webdriver**, софт смотрит видео в браузерах **chrome**.
По роду деятельности софта приходится открывать **кучу браузеров с видео.**
Обработка видео **сильно грузит цп**, есть ли способы как то очень сильно **сжать картинку**, чтобы она практически не грузила цп, а запросы на сайт о просмотре видео шли?

Comment: Как-то странно при явном желании заработать на решении - ожидать что кто-то его предоставит бесплатно

Comment: ну так предлагайте цену)
что я, против чтоли